# White sheen over texture

Tags: texturing, lighting

I'm very new to blender, so please go easy on me. I've had this issue in other files and I am at my wits end trying to figure it out. Essentially, the lighting seems to be adding a milky sheen over my ground texture, it's not happening to my grass textures. It's as if there's a layer of frost over the ground. When I turn down the light it gets better, when I change the colour of the light it changes along with it (Still undesirable as in the real world light does not create a milky layer). I am using an HDR, so still get the white layer even when mixed with coloured light.

I am sure the answer is very simple and I havent stumbled across the solution yet. Any help is greatly appreciated

**Image 03** This is the texture I'm trying to use - nice and dark

**Image 02** This is a snip of the texture in blender. Notice how the grass isn't washed out, but the ground is. I know this is zoomed in, so will appear different - but when I zoom in on my texture in Gimp it's not milky

**Image 01** This is my node setup for the ground

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me that you are using a glossiness texture in the roughness input.
you can read about different texture maps [here](https://help.poliigon.com/general-information/what-are-the-different-texture-maps-for)

try to invert your gloss map and maybe remove your reflection map.

the invert node can be found by pressing Shift + A >color>invert